# align a div to the left a header to the center and a div to right horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a css header that has a div, a h1 and a div. I am having a challenge of aligning the div content to the left, the header to the center and the second div to the right horizontally with content of the second div placed on top of one another.

**css snippets**

```
#header {
            height: 166px;

          background-color: #ccc;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: black;
          margin-bottom:3px;
          padding: 2px;
          text-align: center;
          width: 100%x;

        }
        #footer {
        height: auto;
        background-color: #ccc;
          font-size: 20px;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: black;
          margin-top: 3px;
          padding: 2px;
          text-align: center;
          width: 100%x;
        }
```

**html snippets**

```
<div id="header">
<div style="float:left; margin-left:40px;">
<img src="${contextPath}/resources/images/chat1.png" width="496" height="90"/>

</div>
<h3 align="center"><strong>Chat Panel</strong></h3>
<div align="right">
<img src="${contextPath}/resources/images/chat2.png" />
<form method="post" action="/logout">
        <input type="submit" value="Leave Chat"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

**bellow is the illustration of what I am trying on**

```
div content                h1 content                          second div
```

kindly assist!

Comment: I think we're going to need an image of what this is **supposed** to look like.

Comment: So you just want them in the same line but spaced out?

Comment: yes with the content of the second place vertically on top of the last element............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this, where you use `flex` to line them up

```css
#header {
  height: 166px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%x;
  display: flex;
}
#header * {
  flex: 1;
}
#header div:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
#header h3 {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

#footer {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%x;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x50/f00" width="296" height="90" />
  </div>
  <h3 align="center"><strong>Chat Panel</strong></h3>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ff0" />
    <form method="post" action="/logout">
      <input type="submit" value="Leave Chat" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can be done with `display: table-cell` if you need to target older browsers

```css
#header {
  height: 166px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
#header * {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#footer {
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 3px;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%x;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x50/f00" width="296" height="90" />
  </div>
  <h3 align="center"><strong>Chat Panel</strong></h3>
  <div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/ff0" />
    <form method="post" action="/logout">
      <input type="submit" value="Leave Chat" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this did the trick but the content of the second div is not at the far right of the screen

Comment: @AndreaRobinson Updated, added `text-align: right;` to the last `div`

Comment: awesome. thanks for the assist! Can I bring down the h1 tag a little with margin-top:20px;

Comment: @AndreaRobinson Of course you can ... updated my answer again

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is what you want:

```css
#header {
  text-align: center;
}

#leftDiv {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

#leftImage {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}

h3 {
  display: inline;
}

#rightDiv {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}

#rightImage {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}

#leaveChat {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="leftDiv">
    <img id="leftImage" src="${contextPath}/resources/images/chat1.png" />
  </div>
  <h3>
  Chat Panel
  </h3>
  <div id="rightDiv">
    <img id="rightImage" src="${contextPath}/resources/images/chat2.png" />
    <form method="post" action="/logout">
      <input id="leaveChat" type="submit" value="Leave Chat"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bbh4qpwm/

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```css
#header {
            height: 166px;

          background-color: #ccc;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: black;
          margin-bottom:3px;
          padding: 2px;
          text-align: center;
          width: 100%x;
        }
        #footer {
        height: auto;
        background-color: #ccc;
          font-size: 20px;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: black;
          margin-top: 3px;
          padding: 2px;
          text-align: center;
          width: 100%x;
        }
```

```html
<div id="header">
<div style="float:left; margin-left:40px;">
<img src="${contextPath}/resources/images/chat1.png" width="496" height="90"/>

</div>
<h3 style="float:left"><strong>Chat Panel</strong></h3>
<div style="float:right">
<img src="${contextPath}/resources/images/chat2.png" />
<form method="post" action="/logout">
        <input type="submit" value="Leave Chat"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d05Lcn1m/